# Convert text string to xml tagging using xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt, dita, dita-ot

If I have

```xml
<p>!!!This should be a note</p>
```

is it possible to convert the `<p>` tags to `<note>` tags using XSL (maybe using the !!! as an identifier?). Note that there would be other `<p>` tags that I wouldn't want to be converted. So the result would be

```xml
<note>!!!This should be a note</note>
```

or

```xml
<note>This should be a note</note>
```

---

Also, if I have

```xml
<p>This is an apiname</p>
```

and I want to use XSL to surround 'apiname' with `<apiname>` tags, example:

```xml
<p>This is an <apiname>apiname</apiname></p>
```

is there a way to do this?

I'm using DITA Open Toolkit to write Markdown, which is then converted to XML behind the scenes. Then, XSL is applied to the XML to display HTML and other formats. This is why I can't just update the XML from the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert only `p` elements that start with `!!!` to `note` elements, you could do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[starts-with(., '!!!')]">
    <note>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </note>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you also want to remove the `!!!` identifier, change the 2nd template to:

```
<xsl:template match="p[starts-with(., '!!!')]">
    <note>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., '!!!')" />
    </note>
</xsl:template>
```

---

I suggest you ask a separate question regarding the `apiname` problem, and clarify:

1. What exactly is `apiname`? Is it the literal string "apiname"?
2. Can a `p` contain more than one occurrence of `apiname`?
3. Which [version of XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153) does your processor support?

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed Not so strange considered it was added a few minutes after I downvoted the other answer.

Comment: I see, I misjudged the interaction

Answer (score -1):

> is it possible to convert the `<p>` tags to `<note>` tags using XSL?

Yes. You can use the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
  <xsl:element name="note">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

If you want to transform only the `<p>` elements whose `text()` content starts with "!!!", use

```
<xsl:template match="p[starts-with(.,'!!!')]">   ...
```

---

> and I want to use XSL to surround 'apiname' with  tags

Also yes, use the following template:
*Remark: you can't use a global variable in a template matching rule in XSLT-1.0*

```
<xsl:variable name="api_replace" select="'apinamereplacement'" />
<xsl:variable name="api" select="'apiname'" />

<xsl:template match="p[contains(text(),'apiname')]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(text(),$api)" />
    <xsl:element name="{$api_replace}">
      <xsl:value-of select="$api" />
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(text(),$api)" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

A complete template could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="api_replace" select="'apinamereplacement'" />
  <xsl:variable name="api" select="'apiname'" />
  
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:element name="note">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="p[contains(text(),'apiname')]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(text(),$api)" />
      <xsl:element name="{$api_replace}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$api" />
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(text(),$api)" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed Is it? OP said quite clearly: *"Note that there would be other `<p>` tags that I wouldn't want to be converted."* I am not even talking about the unnecessary complexity.

Comment: no I did the upvote as by your answer

Comment: I don't think you should have. It's not a good answer.

Comment: As you may not have noted, the second code block addresses the issue of not all `<p>` elements being converted. But whatever.